# Trying to get a string that represents a class heirachy

Tags: c#

```
class Base
{
}
class A: Base
{
}
class B:A
{
}
```

I want to be able to get for an instance of B the string "Base.A.B"

Of course I could simply do

```
class B:A
{
   const string NAME = "Base.A.B";
}
```

But thats kind of fragile, if I change things I have to change it in many places

I started out with

```
class Base
{
protected string Name {get{return typeof(Base).Name;}};
}
```

With the dea of each class hierarchy level calling its base.Name method. But again I have now had to name Base twice (admittedly it will fail at compile time if I forget) but it still seems fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same code as others, but I went to the effort, so I am going to damn well post it (the only difference is I didn't want ".object" stuck on the end).

```
    public class Class1 { }
    public class Class2 : Class1 { }
    public class Class3 : Class2 { }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class3 c3 = new Class3();
        Console.WriteLine(TypeToString(c3.GetType()));
    }

    private string TypeToString(Type t)
    {
        if (t == null)
            return "";
        if ((t.BaseType == null) || (t.BaseType == typeof(object)))
            return t.Name;
        return TypeToString(t.BaseType) + "." + t.Name;
    }
```

Comment: u win because yr solution doesnt have '.object' on the front (as per the 'spec'). Both recursive answers get karma tho

Answer (score 3):

This method:

```
public static string GetHierarchy(Type t)
{
    if (t == null)
    {
        return "";
    }

    string rec = GetHierarchy(t.BaseType);

    return rec + "." + t.Name.ToString();
}
```

When called like this:

```
string str = GetHierarchy(typeof(B));
```

Will produce the following result:

```
".Object.Base.A.B"
```

*Edited to prevent NullReferenceException*

Comment: i was going to accept this answer till I saw Michaels answer, he didnt tack '.object' on the resulting string. But both get ++ for nice clean solution - tx

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
class Base {
   public virtual string GetName() { return "Base"; }
}

class A : Base {
   public override string GetName() { return base.GetName() + ".A"; }
}

class B : A  {
   public override string GetName() { return base.GetName() + ".B"; }
}
```

just an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Reflection.

You can annotate your classes like

```
[Name("Base")]
public class Base { }

[Name("A:Base")]
public class A : Base { }

[Name("B:A:Base")]
public class B : A { }
```

Then you can use for example:

```
System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(B));
```

which gives you attr[0] == "B:A:Base"

Answer (score 0):

This is building off of @Jaime's answer so I'll give him most of the credit, but I modified it so that you don't have to put custom attributes in that require you to remember to update them.

*You'll need to add a reference to System.Reflection

```
class Base
{
    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString();
    }
}

class A : Base
{
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return base.GetName() + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString();

    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return base.GetName() + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString();
    }
}

class C : B
{
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return base.GetName() + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString();
    }
}

C test = new C();
test.GetName(); // Yields "Base.A.B.C"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written the following extension method and recursive method.
I believe it provides a good solution to this problem.

Check it out, any feedback will be nice =)

```
public static class FamilyTreeExtension
    {
        public static string GetFamilyTree(this Type t)
        {
            return GetFamilyTreeRecursive(t, t.Name);
        }

        public static string GetFamilyTreeRecursive(Type t, string leaf)
        {
            Type baseType = t.BaseType;

            string currentTree;

            if (baseType != null)
            {
                currentTree = string.Format("{0}.{1}", baseType.Name, leaf);
                return GetFamilyTreeRecursive(baseType, currentTree);
            }
            else
            {
                return leaf;
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
...
private void reflectionTryOut()
        {
            string validate = typeof(C).GetFamilyTree();
        }
    }

    public class A
    {}

    public class B : A
    {}

    public class C : B
    {}
```

Results: **Object.A.B.C**